# Having problems inserting Greek/Turkish/Polish letters into mysql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm reading the word `Αθήνα` from a table which is utf8_unicode_ci encoded and can display it without problem on a utf-8 HTML page. i scrape some more greek and also this is shown correctly. now i want to write the information back to the database in another utf8 table. but the results are this: `?????` or `Î?Î¸Î®Î½Î±`(when i use utf8_encode() on it).
I also set

```
$this -> mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

What am I doing wrong, this is driving me crazy? Any help appreciated thx a lot!

its basically

read out:

```
    $result = $this -> mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `A` WHERE `country_code` = 'GRC'");
    /* Tell browser to use UTF-8 */
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    /* The actual scrape loop, done for every found entry in the urls table*/
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $this -> urls_array[] = $row;
    }
```

write back:

```
$deal=$this -> urls_array[$key];
$this -> mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `B` (`city_name`,`title`....) 
        VALUES (
            '{$deal["city_name"]}',
            '{$title}'
            )
            ");
```

Comment: Please show more code. What are you scraping from where?

Comment: its not only scraping the problem, alreading reading greek from the database and write the immediately same back to another table doesnt work. its stored in an array with `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` and `mb_detect_encoding` tells me its indeed utf8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing "SET NAMES utf8" before inserting anything. There's a modern way of doing it but nonetheless this should work.

Comment: will try that but shouldnt the `set_charset("utf8")`not already take care of it?

Comment: Need more information then. Is the `Content-Type` of the page `text/html; charset=utf-8`?.

Comment: i use: `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` And chrome tells its utf8, but also the echo of the city is shown correctly, but does it matter if for example the city is read written directly (mysql->array->mysql)!?

Comment: can it be a mbstring problem? do i need to have this activated?

Comment: problem solved, it was my own stupidity, checked everything for utf8, except the row itself....it was latin1.......why is that even possible?